# Install nuget package jetbrains rider

Tags: c#, rider

I would like to install a package i downloaded called swatch.AutofacConfiguration.1.3.0.nupkg

I have it stored locally. I just dont know how to install it.

I have tried using commands like
nuget install
nuget add -Source some/directory my.nupkg

I would like to add it to my solution please

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would suggest is instead of using the PMC (Package Manager Console) in Visual Studio use the Nuget Package Manager (which you can find by typing into the search bar at the top of the IDE).

Since the file extension is nupkg you can most definitely find it on there and have visual studio handle the installation and referencing. I hope that helps.

Comment: Swatch360 is using Rider, not VIsual Studio Code.

Comment: I see thank you, in that case I would recommend he follow the docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_NuGet.html